# Matlab: vectorizing update for annotation variable

Tags: matlab, annotations, vectorization

Using Matlab, I've created a graphical user interface that involves 100 circles on the screen. I've stored the handle of each annotation within a vector called neurons. At every iteration, I want to move each circle by a certain amount. These displacements are stored within a matrix called displacement, where the ith row gives the displacement vector for the ith neuron. I update the positions of each circle using the get/set commands within a for loop.

```
    for i=1:length(neurons)
        neuronPos=get(neurons(i),'Position');
        neuronPos=neuronPos+displacement(i,:);
        set(neurons(i),'Position',neuronPos);
    end;
```

The above code works just fine. But I want to know how to vectorize this operation, if possible. I know that using the get command, I can obtain a position matrix of all circles (it actually returns a cell, but can be easily converted using cell2mat).

```
get(neurons,'Position');
```

But I can't figure out a way to use the set command to update the position of all circles at the same time. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should enclose the property within `{}` and `neuronPos` should be a column cell array with positions in each cell:

```
set(neurons, {'position'}, neuronPos)
```